# How to move on after Meteor tutorial?

Tags: meteor

So I just finished the tutorial for a to-do application over at https://www.meteor.com/install. I can't find any place online that can do any tutorials to further push my knowledge on meteor. Is there any tutorials or books to help push my knowledge on Meteor? What direction should I go in?

Comment: Seeking for tutorials is off-topic here. But you should really start your own project to practice your newly learnt knowledge

Comment: +1 For raptor. Build an app. That will force you to really learn. It doesn't have to be huge but it should at a minimum have users (using the accounts package), should accept input from the user, and should offer different users personalized views of the data. Make it mobile responsive with bootstrap 3. Have it send email. Make it so easy to use your mother can use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build your own app, you will learn a lot. I don't know why people think they will learn everything from tutorials. That's misconception.

Steps:

1. Start building your app.
2. If you get stuck, Google how to do something you want to do.
3. Repeat step 2 until you finish your app.

Comment: Without working examples, recruiters/hiring staff won't consider you skilled in said language/platform.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.discovermeteor.com/ is a great source of learning Meteor.
I learned a lot from https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope and https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope app described in their book.

Answer (score 2):

Discover Meteor should be the next step. In that book they are building a lot more complex app than the Meteor tutorial shows. Afterwards I recommend the tutorials on Kadira Academy. If this is done, you are ready to do your own project :)